# Version Control Between Two Offline System

Tags: github, version-control

I'm using github for version control. But client says that they couldn't use github or any version control that connected to internet.

In this case, what is the right way for update client's code?  I have searched in stackoverflow and there are some solutions like fossil and bazaar. But I'm not sure that if they are right solutions.

Comment: Do you expect to be onsite to update their code if there is no Internet connection. Do they have an internal network or are they truly airgapped?

Comment: @osowskit they have internal network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using github for version control

GitHub is a collaboration tool running on top of Git. You and your client can still use Git to collaborate on software development. There are a number of options that will run on their internal network and won't require access to the internet.

> what is the right way for update client's code

1. Serverless Development - Each machine has a Git repository and you share code by generating and applying patches, [`git-format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch).
2. [Host a Git Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server) - Your client can set up a server that hosts a remote Git repository on their network. You can push and pull to different machines.
3. Host GitHub (or other collaboration tool) on their servers - Since you mentioned Github, your customer can install their Enterprise version or choose from a variety of Git solutions.